# Transfer data from segue to segue with different navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I want to transfer data from the view on the bottom right to the one on the upper right. Thanks in advance.. :)

[image]

Comment: use prepare for segue to pass data from one VC to another VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 1. Give your segue a identifier, "make sure the identifier should be created from Controller"

    2. use this function
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {
                let dvc = segue.destination as! yourVC

                `// pass data 
                dvc.data = data
            }
        }
```

Comment: i have runtime error using this.. :(

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let vc = nav.viewControllers[0] as! RewardsRedeemViewController
        vc.reward = arr[cellIndex]
    }

Comment: i have tried your answer but it happens and it worked. The problem is that the navigation bar doesn't appear.. what can i do about that?

Comment: check your view hierarchy does it contains navigation item ..?

Comment: hmm.. so, do I have to have a navigation controller to connect the bottom right to upper right view?

Comment: then i guess your navigation bar should be shown, unless you have programatically hidden in your vc.

Comment: i got it!! the answer was to connect the segue to the navigation controller or the destination.. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you search are unwind segues.

You can find a good how to about segues in this article from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

Especially interesting for you should be the section "Creating an Unwind Segue".

The result should then be similar to this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use it's override method to pass data

1) apply segue.identifier in storyBoard

2) In Action add `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"addTask" , sender: indexPath)`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "addTask" {
            let taskData:Task?
            let vc = segue.destination as! AddTaskVC
            vc.taskData = taskList[indexpath.row]
            vc.isUpdateTask = isEditTask
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this when you set segue from first controller to third. Do check for identifier names while creating segue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
{
    if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier1" 
    { 
       let nextScene = segue.destination as? UIViewController 
       nextScene.stringUserName = "Mike"
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier2"
    {
       let laterScene = segue.destination as? UIViewController 
       laterScene.count = 5
    }
}
```

If you still find and error, please show the error